# Regex: select entire line if both strings are a match

Tags: regex, string

Below is a partial list of the text report I have to work with. The report is overly verbose and I wanted to see if regex (or some other tool) can remove the lines when the string between `orig=` and `)` matches the string between `cust=` and `)`

I've dabbled in regex, but I couldn't figure it out. I'm not even sure if regex is appropriate for something like this...

While this example set only shows there, the data will contain periods and numbers.

```
action:::include:::pageheader
    id:::(orig=pageHeader),(cust=pageHeader)
action:::clientarea:::clientarea
    id:::(orig=clientarea),(cust=clientarea)
action:::tabgroup:::maintabs
    id:::(orig=maintabs),(cust=maintabs)
    style:::(orig=form),(cust=form)
action:::tab:::results
    default:::(orig=true),(cust=true)
    id:::(orig=results),(cust=results)
    label:::(orig=List),(cust=List)
    type:::(orig=list),(cust=list)
action:::menubar:::actiontoolbar
    event:::(orig=search),(cust=search)
    id:::(orig=actiontoolbar),(cust=actiontoolbar)
    sourcemethod:::(orig=getAppSearchOptions),(cust=getAppSearchOptions)
```

Comment: So, from your example input, it'd remove all indented lines? Also are you applying this with any specific programming language? Some regex engines have different features/behave slightly differently than others.

Comment: I am using editplus to perform a search and replace

Comment: idents don't need to be removed. i can do a second pass for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what tool you are using. Assuming Perl-based regex syntax:

```
^.*\(orig=([^)]*)\).*\(cust=\1\).*$
```

This assumes that the text inside `(orig=...)` does not contain closing bracket `)`.

**Update**

With EditPlus's elementary level of support for [regular expressions](http://editplus.info/wiki/Regular_expression_syntax), it is not possible to accomplish the task that you want. In particular, **back-reference** is necessary, but the feature is missing from **searching** with regex.

I suggest that you use different text editor to accomplish the task.

Comment: the regex seems to only pick up values that equal the value of 1.

Comment: Are you aware of any freeware or open source Win32 text editors that support the back-reference you mention?

Comment: @SunWKim: Notepad++ and SublimeText are the 2 that I know of.